Setting up cognito in an Android project with Kotlin SDK
I am confused on how I am to create my user pool in my code and then add sign and sign up features with cognito.
I tried searching github for example projects and did find one but was told it was AWS SDK for Android and that kotlin sdk is the preferred one to use.
